# Putting NavigationToolbar in different Window/ Panel as Figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, wxpython, toolbar

Up front, I am using wxPython-4.0.4, Python 3.7.2 and matplotlib 3.0.3 on Windows 10. Here's my issue.

I would like to have a (large) figure and the NavigationToolbar embedded into wxPython. The figure should be scrollable while the toolbar should remain where it is. My approach was to place the figure into a scrollable panel (wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel) and put the toolbar on top into the main panel. This is my code below:

```
import wx

locale = wx.Locale.GetSystemLanguage()  # fix to 'wx._core.wxAssertionError'

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel


class Main_Panel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        ### Create Widgets
        self.plot_panel = ScrolledPanel(self)

        self.figure = Figure((10,10))               # creating figure and toolbar
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.plot_panel, -1, self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas)

        self.subplot = self.figure.add_subplot(111) # just some arbitrary plot
        self.subplot.plot([1,2,3], [2,4,1])

        ### Implement Widgets
        self.plot_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)  # sizer for scrollable plot panel
        self.plot_sizer.Add(self.toolbar)           # putting toolbar here does work but it is also scrolling
        self.plot_sizer.Add(self.canvas)
        self.plot_panel.SetSizer(self.plot_sizer)
        self.plot_panel.SetupScrolling()

        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)  # sizer for main panel
##        self.main_sizer.Add(self.toolbar)         # putting toolbar here does not work
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.plot_panel, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    app.locale = wx.Locale(locale)  # fix to 'wx._core.wxAssertionError'

    frame = wx.Frame(None)
    Main_Panel(frame)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that I cannot place figure and toolbar into two different panels. If I put them into the same on, the toolbar does not remain on screen if I scroll (obviously). But if I try and add it to the "top" panel via the "main_sizer", it either does not show up at all or it is also scrollable inside the "ScrolledPanel" but is not working.

I also tried placing the whole part with the "ScrolledPanel" into a seperate class but I could not get the toolbar to work either.

Does anybody have a solution for this? Is it even possible at all? Do I have to and can I even create my own toolbar?

Additionally, why do I need to put the two lines into the Code with the comment "fix to wx._core.wxAssertionError'" in order for the program to run without said error?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody has replied to my post yet, I want to post a possible approach that I just found [here](https://sukhbinder.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/matplotlib-with-wxpython-example-with-panzoom-functionality/).

In this example, the toolbar is created but not implemented in the UI and hidden through `self.toolbar.Hide()`.
The functionalities of the toolbar are then accessed via wx buttons and the toolbars attributes: `self.toolbar.zoom()`. This way, the Buttons can be placed somewhere else in the window and possibly even in another window, though I have not tested the latter.

I hope this will at least help others somewhat if noone comes around with a better solution.

As for the `wx._core.wxAssertionError`, I still do not know how to solve it. Especially, since this error appeared almost every time I wanted to try out some sample code that creates the toolbar in one way or another. Sometimes my workaround in the post helped but other times it did not.